# What 'drawImage' really mean when move an image using keyboard?

Tags: java, html, object, keyboard, drawimage

I am starting to learn HTML5 and JavaScript. I have learned AS before in flash and now try to move on. I taught myself to code, I am not a programmer and I have tried search Google for a clear answer that it popped up in my mind.

Recently, I have tried coding follow a book, and I found that it use drawImage() to move the character. At first, I skip on some part about background thing because I just want to know how to move image on .x and .y here using keyboard input. Then, I found that it was not only moving the image but recreated the old one so I ended up have many images that change the position when I pressed a button. However, I changed the position of background creator to a function so it will recreated it every time the program check it. And the problem was gone.

There are screencaps [(1)](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/t31.0-8/10460582_10205909052302969_3559555530824131660_o.jpg), [(2)](https://scontent-sin.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t31.0-8/11075200_10205909052422972_8074847779380739652_o.jpg) so you can see what I said

Right here is what I want to know.

Is this mean the program add new file to a stage or not?

If yes --

What if the image I use is not just a vector created in the program, like a large file, will it cause the program to be slow?

If no --

Then, when you try to code something like this ( move image) you also have to  drawimage of the BG too... it is just like that in JavaScript?

---

Later, my friend say that there is no move in JavaScript, like in AS, you only add new thing with new position and need to clear the canvas. Is this true?

Comment: Yes! I'm sorry that my posted is unclear. Now I've fixed it.

Comment: To my knowledge you must at least clear the parts of the canvas, where some object has moved from last frame. But its easier to clear the whole canvas.

Comment: Yes, clearing canvas is a thing that must be done. 
For an update, someone told me that 'drawimage' is to 'create' new image, not just 'moving' it.